# How I can send user's location in telegram with aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram

I already tried search this in Google. But I couldn't find the answer. I want to bot send user's location. Here is the final version(It doesn't work):

```
markup_request = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
    KeyboardButton('Send your contact ☎️', request_contact=True)
).add(
    KeyboardButton('Send your location ️', request_location=True)
)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['location'])
async def message_for_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Location', reply_markup=markup_request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check your imports.
Secondly, use other methods, instead of  try <send_message> or . Reason is updating of aiogram library.